# Flutter Navigation 2.0. Go directly into another router

Tags: flutter, flutter-navigation

There is a problem navigating between screens.

For example. I have 2 different routers (`cart_router` and `address_router`).

In the `address_router` I have a path `addAddress` that includes two pages (`DeliveryAddressPage` and `AddAddressPage`).

In the `cart_router` I have a path `cartInfo` that includes few pages (`CartDetails`, `DeliveryInfo`...).

So there is a case where I need to go from the DeliveryInfo page to AddAddressPage and back.

What is the best way to do this so as not to include the entire  `address_router` into `cart_router`?

Thanks!